# Space Invaders: Getting the aliens to move as one

Tags: c++, movement

I'm having issues getting my invaders to move together. Currently they hit the edge of the screen and then go crazy.

Here is the code for the Alien:

```
#include "Alien.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
Alien::Alien()
{
}


void Alien::Init(ISprite * a,  float hp, float vp, int sValue)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    alien = a;
    horizontalPos = hp;
    verticalPos = vp;
    rev = false;
    bombInterval = float(rand() % 10 + 1);
    lastDropped = 0;
    scoreValue = sValue;
    alive = true;
}

bool Alien::testCollision(Rocket R)
{
    if(R.getX() >= horizontalPos &&
       R.getX() <= (horizontalPos + 32) &&
       R.getY() >= verticalPos &&
       R.getY() <= (verticalPos + 32)) {
           return true;
}

    return false;
}

void Alien::Update(float move, DResourceManager& drm)
{


    if(rev){
            horizontalPos -= (move);
    }
    else{   
        horizontalPos += (move);
    }

    if(horizontalPos >= (640-32))
    {
        drm.alert();
    }
    if(horizontalPos < 32)
    {
            drm.alert();
    }
        // Check to see if we are colliding with any rockets.
        if(drm.getRocketCount() > 0)
        {
            for(std::vector<Rocket>::iterator roit = drm.getRockets().begin(); roit != drm.getRockets().end(); ++roit) {
            if(roit->alive){
                if(testCollision(*roit))
                {
                    setDead();
                    roit->setDead();
                    drm.getRockets().erase(roit);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


    }
}

int Alien::getScore()
{
    return scoreValue;
}

void Alien::reverse()
{
    rev = !rev;
}

bool Alien::isAlive()
{
    if(alive){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void Alien::setDead()
{
    alive = false;
}    
float Alien::getX()
{
    return horizontalPos;
}

float Alien::getY()
{
    return verticalPos;
}

void Alien::setPosX(float x)
{
     horizontalPos += x;
}

void Alien::setPosY(float y)
{
     verticalPos += y;
}

void Alien::draw()
{   

        alien->draw(int(horizontalPos),  int(verticalPos));
}

void Alien::destroy()
{
    alien->destroy();
}



Alien::~Alien(void)
{
}
```

And the update and draw functions of my DResourceManager class.

```
void DResourceManager::update(float time)
{
    player->update(time, this);
    int direction = 1;
    float max = 0;
    float min = 0;
    for(std::vector<Alien>::iterator it = aliens.begin(); it != aliens.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it ->isAlive()){
            it->Update(time, *this);
        }
    }
    if (rev)
    {
        for(std::vector<Alien>::iterator it = aliens.begin(); it != aliens.end(); ++it)
        {
            it->setPosY(5);
            it->reverse();
            rev = false;
        }
    }


    // Update rockets if we have any.
    if(rocketCount > 0){
        for(std::vector<Rocket>::iterator roit = rockets.begin(); roit != rockets.end();     ++roit) {
            if(roit == rockets.end()){
                return;
            }
                if(roit->alive){
                    roit->update(time);
                }
            }
    }

}


/* Draw all objects to the screen */
void DResourceManager::draw()
{
    player->draw();

    for(std::vector<Alien>::iterator it = aliens.begin(); it != aliens.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->isAlive())
            it->draw();
    }

    for(std::vector<Rocket>::iterator it = rockets.begin(); it != rockets.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->alive)
            it->draw();
    }
}
```

Your help with getting these aliens to move as one would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/space-invaders-type-game-keeping-the-enemies-aligned-with-each-other-as-they-tu

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your code, but I would recommend having a position for "the group" and then have each alien have its own "offset" position from that group position. Then when you draw them you add the two together, and to move the group you move the one group position.